# R for loop to populate new variable

Tags: r, for-loop

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I am at a loss with my for loop and I'm pretty sure it is a minor problem. I did browse through the loop questions that have already been asked...

Here is what I have so far:

```
xvals <- as.matrix(seq(1,10, 1))
```

I would like to create ovals based on ovals

```
yvals <- for (i in 1:nrow(xvals)){
  p <- 2.69/(1+2.69)
  if (i == 1){
    yvals[i,] <- round(p, 2)}
  else {
    yvals[i,] <- round(1-(p)^i, 2)}
}
```

Unfortunately, this thing keeps throwing an error

```
Error in 1:nrow(xvals) : argument of length 0
```

When I change xvals to matrix, I get a different error:

```
Error in yvals[i, ] <- round(p, 2) : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the loop

```
xvals <- 1:10
p <- 2.69/(1+2.69)
yvals <- 1-p^xvals
yvals[1] <- p
yvals <- round(yvals, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually want a matrix or will a vector do?

```
yvals <- replicate(10,0)

p <- 2.69/(1+2.69)
for (i in 1:length(yvals)){
  if (i == 1){
    yvals[i] <- round(p, 2)
}
  else {
    yvals[i] <- round(1-(p)^i, 2)}
}

xvals <- 1:10

plot(xvals, yvals)
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to use the xvals and yvals variable to plot the datapoints against each other, so I guess a vector would do??

Comment: Do I have to take the p-variable out of the for loop?

Comment: No you don't, but since the p variable is the same for each iteration of the loop, it's technically smarter to just put it outside of the loop.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first create empty matrix to achieve loop to work. Try this, maybe it helps you

```
xvals <- as.matrix(seq(1,10, 1))
xvals

yvals <- matrix(0, nrow=nrow(xvals),ncol=ncol(xvals))
yvals
for (i in 1:nrow(xvals)){
p <- 2.69/(1+2.69)
  if (i == 1){
    yvals[i,] <- round(p, 2)}
  else {
    yvals[i,] <- round(1-(p)^i, 2)}
}
yvals
```